# function worked automatically (constructor) when file required in node.js

Tags: node.js

I couldnt write function worked automatically (constructor) when file required in node.js..

this is so...file.js

```
module.exports = {

  index: function () {

      //code here

  }

};
```

app.js

```
var file=require("./file");
res.send(file.index());
```

what I want...

```
module.exports = {

      main :__constructor()
      {
         this.name="blabla";
      },
      index: function () {

          //code here
          this.name // will be used this place name variable

      }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prototype()` to do this. Hope it helps!

```js
const App = function(name) {
  this.name = name
}

App.prototype.main = function() {
  return this.name
}

b = new App('myName')
console.log(b.main())

//You can do module.exports = App and invoke it in another file
```

Answer (score 0):

okey..but

```
module.exports = {

  app :function (name)
  {
    this.name="blabla";
  },
  app.prototype.index: function () {

 }

};
```

this does not work!!!

/var/www/public/nodeapi/app/v1/blog/index.js:19
 app.prototype.index: function () {

```js
const App = function(name) {
  this.name = name
}

App.prototype.main = function() {
  return this.name
}

b = new App('myName')
console.log(b.main())

//You can do module.exports = App and invoke it in another file
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
// file.js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'blabla';
  }
  index() {
    console.log('name', this.name);
  }
}

module.exports = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

class blog {

```
constructor()
{

this.name="fookey";

}

index(callback)
{
   var data={};
   data.test=this.name;
   callback(data);
}

}

module.exports=new blog();
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

why does not work?